# How to log a library variable in java?

Tags: java, android, debugging, logging, libraries

I want to log a variable value in an external library(AppCompat in android).

Is it possible somehow? I know I can hit a breakpoint and check a value, but I want to check many touch event callbacks that are very hard to debug with this way

For example, code is:

```
int setHeaderTopBottomOffset(CoordinatorLayout parent, V header, int newOffset,
    int minOffset, int maxOffset) {
    final int curOffset = getTopAndBottomOffset();
    int consumed = 0;

    if (minOffset != 0 && curOffset >= minOffset && curOffset <= maxOffset) {
          // If we have some scrolling range, and we're currently within the min and max
          // offsets, calculate a new offset
          newOffset = MathUtils.constrain(newOffset, minOffset, maxOffset);

          if (curOffset != newOffset) {
              setTopAndBottomOffset(newOffset);
              // Update how much dy we have consumed
              consumed = curOffset - newOffset;
          }
      }

      return consumed;
 }
```

And I want to log cases when `curOffset != newOffset` and log out `curOffset` and `newOffset`

Comment: Please provide specific details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in IDEA by setting a breakpoint on the line you are interested in, then right-click on the breakpoint, uncheck `Suspend` option and fill in `Evaluate and log` with something like `Log.d(TAG, debugMessage)`